# передать текст из textview в другое Activity используя LayoutInflater и .xml файл в нем

Tags: java, android

есть два textview тут:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
TextView text_1;
TextView text_2;
Button button11;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch  (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            intent.putExtra("1",text_1.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("2",text_2.getText().toString());
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button11=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button11.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

пересылаются сюда:

```
public class Second2 extends MainActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
    LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linLayout);
    LayoutInflater ltInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View item = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, linLayout, false);
    item.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    linLayout.addView(item);

    /*/String txtNamebl = getIntent().getStringExtra("1");
    String txtNameost = getIntent().getStringExtra("2");

    TextView tvName_bl = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tv_bl);
    tvName_bl.setText(txtNamebl);
    TextView tvName_os = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tv_os);
    tvName_os.setText(txtNameost);/*/-'из-за этого крашится приложение, при layoutinflater этот код не работает, а при обычной передаче между активити все ок.

}
```

и подтягивается `item.xml` в котором находятся `textview`-получатели

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_bl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="24sp">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_os"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
</TextView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Наверное должен быть какой-то адаптер? подскажите плз как правильно.

Стактрейс

```
07-27 20:23:25.959 966-966/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                           java.lang.NullPointerException
                                               at com.example.roma.listviewown.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:22)
                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: я вам гарантирую, что никто не понял, причем тут адаптер, и что вы вообще хотите

Comment: @metalgurus, про адаптер я предположил лишь, я не знаю), а хочу отправить текст из textview (main activity) в другое Activity, но в другом вызывается item.xml с помощью layoutinflater(где и находятся нужные текствьюшки, которые должны принять из мейнактивити текст).

Comment: Ок, а теперь объясните, что вы хотите от нас? У вас же написан код, который  передает все.

Comment: В MainActivity точно все правильно, в Second из-за того, что есть layoutinflater , обычный код на прием (что у меня и есть) - не работает, и приложение крашится. От вас, я хочу узнать как правильно передать интенты в Second2,  и чтобы оно работало с item.xml.

Comment: Вот, мы уже подходим ближе к решению. А теперь выложите стактрейс ошибки, с которой оно крашится.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, как это сделать ?) Скопировать logcat? Сорри за элементартные вопросы, но я в начале пути)

Comment: да, в logCat при краше показывает стактрейс ошибки красным.

Comment: обновил тело письма, там стактрейс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка возникает из за того, что вы не инициализировали переменные

```
TextView text_1;
TextView text_2;
```

И пытаетесь их использовать

```
intent.putExtra("1",text_1.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("2",text_2.getText().toString());
```

Добавьте в onCreate() их инициализацию:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button11=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button11.setOnClickListener(this);
    //вот тут
    text_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.<тут айдишник>);
    text_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.<тут айдишник>);
}
```

Comment: Блин, сорри, этого вопроса вообще не должно было быть, элементарно не доглядел, и устроил панику)